# Why doesn't my OpenCL 3d image lookup work?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, opencl

I have been having trouble with an OpenCL kernel which I've written producing incorrect results (compared to a reference brute-force CPU implementation).

I tracked the problem down to a 3D lookup table I'm using which seems to be returning garbage results, rather than the values which I passed in.

I have the following (simplified) OpenCL kernel for reading a precomputed function from a 3D image type:

```
__constant sampler_t legSampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;

inline float normalizedLegendre(int n, int m, float z, image3d_t legendreLUT)
{
  float nCoord = (((float) n) / get_image_width(legendreLUT));
  float mCoord = (((float) m) / get_image_height(legendreLUT));
  float zCoord = ((z + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
  float4 coord = (float4)(floor(nCoord) + 0.5f, floor(mCoord) + 0.5f, zCoord, 0.0f);

  return read_imagef(legendreLUT, legSampler, coord).x;

}

_kernel void noiseMain(__read_only image3d_t legendreLUT, __global float* outLegDump)
{

  //k is the linear index into the array.
  int k = get_global_id(0);

  if(k < get_image_depth(legendreLUT))
  {
    float z = ((float) k / (float) get_image_depth(legendreLUT)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float legLookup = normalizedLegendre(5, 4, z, legendreLUT);
    float texCoord = ((float) k / 1024.0) * 2 - 1;
    outLegDump = legLookup;
  }
}
```

On the host side, I generate the 3D image, legendreLUT, using the following code:

```
  static const size_t NLEGPOLYBINS = 1024;
  static const size_t NLEGPOLYORDERS = 16;
  boost::scoped_array<float> legendreHostBuffer(new float[NLEGPOLYORDERS * NLEGPOLYORDERS * NLEGPOLYBINS]);
  float stepSize = 1.0 / (((float) NLEGPOLYBINS/2.0) - 0.5);

  float z = -1.0;

  std::cout << "Generating legendre polynomials..." << std::endl;

  for(size_t n = 0; n < NLEGPOLYORDERS; n++)
    {
      for(size_t m = 0; m < NLEGPOLYORDERS; m++)
    {
      for(size_t zI = 0; zI < NLEGPOLYBINS; zI++)
        {
          using namespace boost::math;
          size_t index = (n * NLEGPOLYORDERS * NLEGPOLYBINS) + (m * NLEGPOLYBINS) + zI;
          //-1..1 in NLEGPOLYBINS steps...
          float val;
          if(m > n) 
        {
          legendreHostBuffer[index] = 0;
          continue;
        }
          else
        {
          //boost::math::legendre_p
          val = legendre_p<float>(n,m,z);
        }

          float nPm = n+m;
          float nMm = n-m;
          float factNum;
          float factDen;

          factNum = factorial<float>(n-m);
          factDen = factorial<float>(n+m);

          float nrmTerm;

          nrmTerm = pow(-1.0, m) * sqrt((n + 0.5) * (factNum/factDen));
          legendreHostBuffer[index] = val;
          z += stepSize;
          if(z > 1.0) z + 1.0;                   
        }
      z = -1.0;
    }
    }

  //DEBUGGING STEP: Dump everything we've just generated for m = 4, n = 5, z=-1..1
  std::ofstream legDump("legDump.txt");

  for(size_t i = 0; i < NLEGPOLYBINS; i++)
    {
      int n =5; int m = 4;
      size_t index = (n * NLEGPOLYORDERS * NLEGPOLYBINS) + (m * NLEGPOLYBINS) + i;

      float texCoord = ((float) i / (float) NLEGPOLYBINS) * 2 - 1;

      legDump << i << " " << texCoord << " " << legendreHostBuffer[index] << std::endl;
    }

  legDump.close();


  std::cout << "Creating legendre polynomial look up table image..." << std::endl;

  cl::ImageFormat legFormat(CL_R, CL_FLOAT);
  //Generate out legendre polynomials image...
  m_legendreTable = cl::Image3D(m_clContext,
                CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                legFormat, 
                NLEGPOLYORDERS,
                NLEGPOLYORDERS,
                NLEGPOLYBINS,
                0,
                0,
                legendreHostBuffer.get());
```

Other than the index, the actual generation of the values is more or less irrelevant, but I've included it here for completeness.

And here is how I execute the kernel and read back the results:

```
  cl::Buffer outLegDump = cl::Buffer(m_clContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, NLEGPOLYBINS * sizeof(float));

  //Create out kernel...
  cl::Kernel kernel(m_program, "noiseMain");


  kernel.setArg(0, m_legendreTable);
  kernel.setArg(1, outLegDump);

  size_t kernelSize = 1024;

  cl::NDRange globalRange(kernelSize);

  cl::NDRange localRange(1);

  m_commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, globalRange, cl::NullRange);
  m_commandQueue.finish();

  boost::scoped_array<float> legDumpHost(new float[NLEGPOLYBINS]);
  m_commandQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(outLegDump, CL_TRUE, 0, NLEGPOLYBINS * sizeof(float), legDumpHost.get());

  std::ofstream legreadback("legreadback.txt");

  for(size_t i = 0; i < NLEGPOLYBINS; i++)
    {
      legreadback << i << " "  << legDumpHost[i] << std::endl;
    }

  legreadback.close();
```

When I look at the dumped data (i.e. that put out in legdump.txt from the host-side buffer), I get the expected data. However, when I compare it to the data received *back* from the device side (i.e. that looked up by the kernel and put out in legreadback.txt), I get incorrect values.

Since I'm calculating 1024 values in both cases, I'll spare everyone the whole dump, however, here are the first few/last values of each:

**legdump.txt (host side sanity check):**

```
0 -0
1 -0.0143913
2 -0.0573401
3 -0.12851
4 -0.227566
5 -0.354175
..
..
1020 0.12859
1021 0.0144185
1022 0.0144185
1023 1.2905e-8
```

**legreadback.txt (device-side lookup and readback)**

```
0 1
1 1 
2 1
3 1
4 0.5
5 0
..
..
1020 7.74249e+11
1021 -1.91171e+15
1022 -3.81029e+15
1023 -1.91173e+15
```

Note that these values are the same across multiple runs of the code, so I don't think it's an initialization problem.

I can only assume that I'm calculating indices wrong somewhere, but I don't know where. I've checked the calculation of the Z coordinate (which naturally is defined on -1..1), its conversion to texture coordinates (0..1 range), and the conversion of M and N to texture coordinates (which should be done without interpolation), and found nothing to be wrong.

So my question is thus:

**What is the proper way to create and index a 3D lookup table in OpenCL?**

Comment: It looks like you've already solved your problem. I'm seeing an issue in `normalizedLegendre`: If seems to mix up normalized and non-normalized math. First you calculate `nCoord` and `mCoord` to be in normalized (0.0 to 1.0 across texture), but then floor then and add 0.5f, which looks more like you're setting up for a non-normalized access: You calculate `coord` to be integers plus 0.5f, but the sampler (`legSampler`) is set for normalized access (`CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE`) and so expects 0.0 to 1.0 across the texture (not pixel coordinates).

Comment: The M and N coordinates are most definitely wrong, but they weren't the problem. I had them coded that way because of another post I had on SO asking how to do interpolation of only one coordinate (Z), and not M or N. Unfortunately, that formula obviously didn't work and I decided to use nearest-neighbor sampling instead, since it's more important to guarantee M and N aren't interpolated than to get a highly accurate result for Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, the problem turned out to be in the indexing on the host-side used to generate the lookup table.

The previous index calculation:

```
 size_t index = (n * NLEGPOLYORDERS * NLEGPOLYBINS) + (m * NLEGPOLYBINS) + zI;
```

Was based on C++ 3D array indexing, which is not the way addressing works in OpenCL for a 3D image. A 3D image can be thought of as a "stack" of 2D images on top of each other, where the depth coordinate (Z in this case) selects the image, and the horizontal and vertical coordinates (m and n in this case) select the pixel within the selected image.

The correct indexing calculation is:

```
size_t index = m * NLEGPOLYORDERS + n + (zI * NLEGPOLYORDERS * NLEGPOLYORDERS);
```

As one can see, this new approach fits the "stacked image" layout described previously, whereas the previous calculation does not.